# connection leak error flagged with datasource proxy with version 1.4.9

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy) version 1.4.9, I am executing a stored procedure using spring entity manager as shown below. I get warning of apparent connection leak at line query.getOutputParameterValue(3). I tested using trace method of datasource-proxy that the connection is closed automatically after the method is executed. Any clues what might be the issue?

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class TestCheckServiceImpl implements TestCheckService{

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public String doCheck(long id, String userName) {

    StoredProcedureQuery query;
    String result="";
    try{

        query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("TEST_PKG.do_check")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class,ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class,ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class,ParameterMode.OUT)
                .setParameter(1, id)
                .setParameter(2,userName); 
        result = (String) query.getOutputParameterValue(3);
    }catch(Exception ex){             
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: A false positive? Is there a real connection leak? It should trigger a "too many connections" exception at some point.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I think so, when I do testing I see connections being closed. Also I do not see too many connections exception. The JMX bean for hikaricp does not show anything weired about active connections.The connection leak detection time is set to 2 seconds. I will increase to 2 mins to verify this.